# I need help with the unkown font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have been to sites with font identifiers and font matcherators, but in vain.
Can any of you help me about the name of this font? It is simple, I can draw that word, but I need more words for the project.
It says "OPTIKA", if that's needed.

[image: font needed]

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - glad to have you here! 

Please look around [tour] to get a sense of who and what this community is about, and look over [ask] and [answer] questions, so that you know both the criteria for successful posing and what you should expect for replies. Whilst you're doing that, I'd also briefly look at [help/behavior] to get a sense of how we as a community prefer folks to interact.

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't see in this *exactly* what and where you've tried - please review this canonical question which explains **GDSE** font-match question criteria:

[What are the requirements for font identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions)

but nonetheless...

Seems to me that both Churchward 69 and Moog are very similar (assuming a significant vertical scale compression having been applied to your sample) and the further differences I see in the lowercase t could well be vector editing differences of a bespoke logotype.

[image]
https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Moog.font?text=OPtIKA

[image]
https://www.whatfontis.com/NFS_Churchward-69-Bold.font?text=OPtIKA

Hope this helps some.